# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch gotNilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am a beginner programmer in Ruby and Ruby on Rails , I'm trying to run a rake command in my task , but when I do the following happens:

```
rake daily_tasks:process_api

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Estado(#47392639701120) expected, got NilClass(#47392580444120)
/home/thiagoamaralr/Desktop/proponente-master-4f8a3b2ddb02a90b2c173cf31383505018d02dd/app/services/create_programa_api.rb:21:in `call'
/home/thiagoamaralr/Desktop/proponente-master-74f8a3b2ddb02a90b2c173cf31383505018d02dd/lib/tasks/daily_tasks.rake:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/thiagoamaralr/Desktop/proponente-master-74f8a3b2ddb02a90b2c173cf31383505018d02dd/lib/tasks/daily_tasks.rake:5:in `each'
/home/thiagoamaralr/Desktop/proponente-master-74f8a3b2ddb02a90b2c173cf31383505018d02dd/lib/tasks/daily_tasks.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => daily_tasks:process_api
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Follow the task I'm trying to run:

```
namespace :daily_tasks do
  desc "Process the day to day tasks"
  task process_api: :environment do

    SiconvApi::Programa.find.each do |programa|
      if programa.data_inicio_recebimento_propostas && (programa.data_inicio_recebimento_propostas.to_date >= Date.parse("2015/06/01"))
        CreateProgramaApi.call(SiconvApi::Serializers::Programa.new(programa))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is content create_programa_api.rb:

```
class CreateProgramaApi
  def self.call(programa_api)
    params = programa_api.to_h
    params[:orgao] = Orgao.where("lower(name) = ?", programa_api[:orgao][:nome].mb_chars.downcase).first_or_create(name: programa_api[:orgao][:nome])
    params[:orgao_vinculado] = Orgao.where("lower(name) = ?", programa_api[:orgao_vinculado][:nome].mb_chars.downcase).first_or_create(name: programa_api[:orgao_vinculado][:nome])
    params[:orgao_executor] = Orgao.where("lower(name) = ?", programa_api[:orgao_executor][:nome].mb_chars.downcase).first_or_create(name: programa_api[:orgao_executor][:nome])
    params[:estados] = []
    if programa_api[:estados].size == 27
      params[:estados] << Estado.find_by(sigla: 'Todos')
    else
      programa_api[:estados].each do |e|
        params[:estados] << Estado.find_by(sigla: e)
      end
    end
    params[:atendes] = [Atende.where("lower(name) = ?", programa_api[:atende_a].mb_chars.downcase).first_or_create(name: programa_api[:atende_a])] if programa_api[:atende_a]
    params.delete(:atende_a)
    programa = Programa.find_by(codigo: programa_api[:codigo])
    if programa
      programa.update(params)
    else
      Programa.create! params
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: The error seems to originate in `app/services/create_programa_api.rb`. Please include the contents of that file in your post.

Comment: @TomLord Hello , I 've edited the post and added the contents of the file create_programa_api.rb

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `nil` object in `params[:estados]`, and Rails can't save this association.
Easiest way to remove them is to call `params[:estados].compact!` after line 14

Answer (score 0):

This block of code is your problem:

```
params[:estados] = []
if programa_api[:estados].size == 27
  params[:estados] << Estado.find_by(sigla: 'Todos')
else
  programa_api[:estados].each do |e|
    params[:estados] << Estado.find_by(sigla: e)
  end
end
```

If no record is found, the `#find_by` returns `nil`. This is why you are getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Estado(#47392639701120) expected, got NilClass
```

When calling `Programa.create!(params)`.

One solution would be to call `params[:estados].compact!` after the `if` statement (this is using [`Array#compact!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-compact-21) to remove any `nil` values).

Or, you could instead write that section of code like this:

```
params[:estados] = Estadio.where(
  sigla: (programa_api[:estados].size == 27 ? 'Todos' : programa_api[:estados])
)
```

With this code, there is no longer a need to call `compact!` since we already end up with an *empty* array if no records are found (i.e. there are no `nil` values).

Note that the behaviour here isn't *quite* the same - what happens if there are multiple `Estado` records with the `sigla` equal to one of `programa_api[:estados]` or `'Todos'`? Previously you were only fetching the "first" such record, whereas now you'd be fetching *all* of them. This may not be an issue (or may even be the correct behaviour!!) - it's just something to be aware of, at least.